# Windows batch script - Regular expression for file names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using below batch script to copy .class files from dir sourcedir2 to dir sourcedir1 based on same matched file names.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir1=U:\sourcedir\changeset"
SET "sourcedir2=U:\sourcedir\target"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir1%\*.java" ') DO (
    SET "javadir=%%~dpa"
    SET "classfile=!javadir:%sourcedir1%=%sourcedir2%!%%~na.class"
    IF EXIST !classfile! ECHO COPY "!classfile!" "%%a"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Addition to this I wanted to copy .class files which are having filename format as classname$number.class (ex :Action$1.class ,Action$2.class) from dir sourcedir2 to dir sourcedir1.

I tried the change for SET classfile as below but also it will copy files which are not in the format of classname$number.class

```
SET "classfile=!javadir:%sourcedir1%=%sourcedir2%!%%~na*.class"
```

Please suggest me Regularexpression to match file names with having only format as classname$number.class or classname.class .

Thank you ..

Comment: Batch files do not support regular expressions.

Comment: If `sourcedir1` contains foo.java, then you want to copy from `sourcedir2` the files foo.class, foo1.class, and foo77.class. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses..  @lit yes your are correct - if sourcedir1 contains foo.java, then I want to copy from sourcedir2 the files foo.class, foo$1.class, and foo$77.class,foo$100.class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find the workaround solution with below script. Thank you.

```
 @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET "sourcedir1=U:\sourcedir\changeset"
    SET "sourcedir2=U:\sourcedir\target"
    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir1%\*.java" ') DO (
        SET "javadir=%%~dpa"
        SET "classfile=!javadir:%sourcedir1%=%sourcedir2%!%%~na.class"
        IF EXIST !classfile! ECHO COPY "!classfile!" "%%a"
SET "innerclassfile=!javadir:%sourcedir1%=%sourcedir2%!%%~na"$"*.class"
        IF EXIST !innerclassfile! ECHO COPY "!innerclassfile!" "%%a"
    )
    GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script copies from sourcedir2 to sourcedir1 based on the filename matching a regex for the class name and any digits before the .class extension. When you are confident that the correct files will be copied, remove the `-WhatIf` from the Copy-Item cmdlet.

```
$sourcedir1 = 'C:\src\t\j1'
$sourcedir2 = 'C:\src\t\j2'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir1 -File -Recurse -Filter '*.java' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $classname = $_.BaseName
        Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir2 -File -Filter "$classname*.class" |
            Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$classname\$[0-9]*\.class" } |
                ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_.FullName $sourcedir1 -WhatIf }
    }
```

To run this from a cmd shell, put the code above into a file such as copyclasses.ps1 and use:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\copyclasses.ps1
```

Comment: Thanks lit for your suggestions .. I wont be allowed to use power shell for 
 now :( . Is there any workaround way to find the files which has "$" char in filenames. like  file$1.class , file$1.class etc... using batch script.